# Dynamically Creating a Singly Linked List in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I have a struct called employee in my program with the following definition:

```
struct employee {
int id;
int age;
struct *employee next;
};
```

How would I take in input from the user, create a struct from their input, and create a singly linked list using pointers? I'm having a lot of issues figuring out how to do this dynamically. In Java, this is easily done through the constructor but how would you do this in C?

EDIT: Assuming the input is simply two ints (id and age).

Comment: I have written a blog post describing implementation of linked lists http://cyberlingo.blogspot.in/2014/11/linked-lists.html

Comment: @karma_geek That's a little too complicated for what I need to do. I'm new to C so this is still rather challenging for me.

Comment: Ok, so first you need to understand the basics of dynamic allocation- how to use malloc, free etc. Also, you must know how pointers work. Your question is very broad, any particular problems that you are facing?

Comment: I am using scan f to accept two integers (as long as both ints aren't 0) with the idea of creating a struct out of them. I also want these structs to be a linked list. So say the user inputs the following: (9, 3) and (3, 2). I would create two structs with the first one (9,3) having a next pointer to the second one (3, 2).

Answer (score 1):

This is how you create a new `employee` struct. You are dynamically allocating the memory using `malloc` function.

```
 struct employee *new_employee = (struct employee*)malloc(sizeof(struct employee));
```

Now, we need to fill the data into this newly created `employee` field:

```
new_employee -> id = input_id;
new_employee -> age = input_age;
```

As for the `next` pointer, it is usually given NULL value. This is to prevent the `next` pointer from pointing to any arbitrary memory location.

```
new_employee -> next = NULL;
```

Finally, we have to `link` the list. To do that, you have to point the `next` pointer of the previous employee field to the current employee field (ex:as you mentioned in comment, first one (9,3) having a next pointer to the second one (3, 2))

Since it is a singly linked list, we cannot backtrack. So, there are two methods to access the previous field.

First is to maintain a pointer that points to the last field of the link list.

Second is to traverse the entire list till the end, and when you reach the last element, change its `next` pointer.

Implementation of the second method:

```
 node *temp = *start;
    if(temp!=NULL)
    {
            while(temp -> next)
                temp = temp -> next;
            temp -> next = new_employee;
     }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

**Note** : ***`don't give me fish teach me how to fish`***

***This is an example :***

```
struct node {
int value;
struct *node next;
};
```

***How to create new Node pointer dynamically ?***

```
node* aux = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
```

***How to get user input ( safely ) ?***

```
char line[256];
int i;
if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) {
    if (1 == sscanf(line, "%d", &i)) {
        /* i can be safely used */
    }
}
```

***How to create a linked list's head ?***

```
/* This will be the unchanging first node */
struct node *root;      
/* Now root points to a node struct */
root = (struct node *) malloc( sizeof(struct node) ); 
/* The node root points to has its next pointer equal to a null pointer 
   set */
root->next = 0;  
/* By using the -> operator, you can modify what the node,
   a pointer, (root in this case) points to. */
root->value = 5;
```

***How to add new node to the linked list ?***

```
/* This won't change, or we would lose the list in memory */
    struct node *root;       
    /* This will point to each node as it traverses the list */
    struct node *conductor;  

    root = malloc( sizeof(struct node) );  
    root->next = 0;   
    root->value = 12;
    conductor = root; 
    if ( conductor != 0 ) {
        while ( conductor->next != 0)
        {
            conductor = conductor->next;
        }
    }
    /* Creates a node at the end of the list */
    conductor->next = malloc( sizeof(struct node) );  

    conductor = conductor->next; 

    if ( conductor == 0 )
    {
        printf( "Out of memory" );
        return 0;
    }
    /* initialize the new memory */
    conductor->next = 0;         
    conductor->value = 42;
```

***Now you must be able to solve the problem easily .***

Happy Coding :D